# how to control Irobot create base?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the packaged I need to install?
What are the nodes that I need to run to control Irobot create base?

Please tell in detail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66587/how-to-control-irobot-create-base?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you could start by looking here : http://www.ros.org/wiki/irobot_create_2_1...

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-04**:
I saw this page, its too much confusing.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-04**:
You could look at here : http://www.kermani.us/index.php/tutorials/ros-tutorial/33-03-ros-tutorial-irobot-create . It is about ROS ELECTRIC so some things might be quite different, but more detailed.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-04**:
hey Lucile, I found this link to be useful at a first look. I hope to perform things well with it. Thanking you in advance